# rake db:migrate runs into an error for an undefined method

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rake, database-migration

I took over a website that was built by somebody else. I'm now trying to get it up and running on localhost. However, when I migrate it looks like the previous developer put code into the migrations that may rely on a seed already being there. The migrate file looks like this.

```
def up
  add_column :supplies, :color, :string

  Supply.where(:title => "Shipped").first.update(:color =>'#e20ce8')
end

def down
  remove_column :supplies, :color
end
```

The error I get on this file when i run rake db:migrate is...

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations 
canceled:

undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try `update_attributes` instead of `update`

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It worked and was a simple yet elegant solution.

Comment: np, I'll submit it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing `rake db:schema:load`?  I believe that would allow you to get going and then allow you to use `rake db:migrate` going forward.

Answer (score 2):

What can be happening is that a previous migration which can be seeding `supply` model is not running or table is truncated. As a good practice we should not seed data with migrations but rather just build the schema with migrations.

You have 2 options:

How about pulling this code and the other seeders in migrations and putting them in `seeds.rb` and running `rake db:seed`

```
#in seeds.rb
Supply.where(:title => "Shipped").first.update(:color =>'#e20ce8')
```

Or,

Check before updating the migration.

```
instance = Supply.where(:title => "Shipped").first
instance.update(color: '#e20ce8') if instance.present?
```